# How to send the newly updated rows to client in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

Currently i am working on **Node.js + MySQL** POC and its works really well as of now... with the rows getting updated or added are automatically notified to all the clients who are connected to socket port. But i feel its bit unnecessary to send all the row ( lets say 100+) each time to all clients as it will not make any sense - **is there any module in node.js which takes the NEWLY inserted or UPDATED rows from mysql send broadcast it clients ?** or ignore the rows / datas are which are already transmitted to clients ?

Thanks.

> ```
> io.sockets.on( 'connection', function (
> socket ) {
>
> console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
>
> if (!connectionsArray.length) {
>     pollingLoop();
> }
>
> socket.on('disconnect', function () {
>     var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf( socket );
>     console.log('socket = ' + socketIndex + ' disconnected');
>     if (socketIndex >= 0) {
>         connectionsArray.splice( socketIndex, 1 );
>     }
> });
>
> console.log( 'A new socket is connected!' );
> connectionsArray.push( socket );
>  });
>
> var updateSockets = function ( data ) {
>
> data.time = new Date();
>
> connectionsArray.forEach(function( tmpSocket ){
>     tmpSocket.volatile.emit( 'notification' , data );
> }); };
> ```

Currently the above code sends all the datas to client. Just wondering to get an idea about opt logic to send only the new or updated one.

MySQL connection codes

> ```
> mysql               = require('mysql'),
> connectionsArray    = [],
> connection          = mysql.createConnection({
>     host        : 'localhost',
>     user        : 'root',
>     password    : 'root',
>     database    : 'nodejs',
>     port        : 3306
> }),
> POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000,
> pollingTimer;
>
> // If there is an error connecting to the database
> connection.connect(function(err) {   // connected! (unless `err` is
> set)   console.log( err ); });
> ```

This is how i am selecting the rows -

> ```
> var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users')
> ```

Comment: If you don't show us your existing code (a minimal version of it, under 20 lines) that demonstrates the current behavior and what you want we won't be able to help you. Also library requests are off topic in Stack Overflow so please phrase your question to not look like one ;)

Comment: Thanks , have updated the code which i tried so far and not requesting for any library - just want to get an idea about the available modules in node to achieve this in MySQL - Cheers :)

Comment: Where is the mysql bits?

Comment: Shared the general mysql code - have used the "select * from" since i am not sure about broadcasting only the updated one.

Comment: Where are you sending the updated data to the sockets though?

Comment: Currently it send ALL the data to client - i am just using the code logic from here - http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/ - Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75044/discussion-between-harry-and-benjamin-gruenbaum).

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? if so, please share the answer. I have this kind of problem also.